# Labeling row-chunks of a dataframe sequentially by context of other column in r

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have an instrument that takes readings at a set time interval, and want to sequentially identify every event when it is active, which can be seen by deviations in a baseline measurement.

I can identify when it is use with an `ifelse()` statement, but I want every set of rows to given an id based on the order those events occurred i.e. event 1, event 2, etc.

Here is a simplified example of the situation in r (the preferred language):

```
original_df <- tribble(

  ~rownum, ~context_val,
  #-------|-------------
  1, 0.2,
  2, 0.3,
  3, 0.2,
  4,  20,
  5,  28,
  6,  22,
  7, 0.4,
  8, 0.2,
  9,  21,
  10, 18,
  11,0.1
)

desired_outcome <- tribble(

  ~rownum, ~context_val, ~sequentail_tag,
  #-------|-------------|----------------
  1, 0.2, NA,
  2, 0.3, NA,
  3, 0.2, NA,
  4,  20,  1,
  5,  28,  1,
  6,  22,  1,
  7, 0.4, NA,
  8, 0.2, NA,
  9,  21,  2,
  10, 18,  2,
  11,0.1, NA


)
```

The `context_val` field will determine when the instrument is in use, and the sequential tag will identify which event the rows belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little convoluted but it works... and you can see the underlying logic...

```
original_df %>% 
mutate(
  runs1 = ifelse(context_val > 15 & lag(context_val < 15), 1, 0), 
  runs2 = cumsum(runs1), 
  sequential_tag = ifelse(context_val > 15, runs2, NA) 
)

# A tibble: 11 x 5
       rownum context_val runs1 runs2 sequential_tag
        <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>
     1      1         0.2     0     0             NA
     2      2         0.3     0     0             NA
     3      3         0.2     0     0             NA
     4      4        20       1     1              1
     5      5        28       0     1              1
     6      6        22       0     1              1
     7      7         0.4     0     1             NA
     8      8         0.2     0     1             NA
     9      9        21       1     2              2
    10     10        18       0     2              2
    11     11         0.1     0     2             NA

>
```

Comment: This will work if I can be smart about my thresholds for determining a new runs1. The actual data will require some more complicated logic because the edges are less pronounced, and there are instances where the context_val jumps for 1 or two readings where I won't want to flag a separate run. This was the real hurdle though, thank you.